# Does cron have an authoritative standards document for cron syntax?

Tags: cron, standards

Searching for examples of Cron usage and Cron parsing tools for cron's syntax, I see some tools with 5 input places and some with 6 (the sixth being for a seconds field).  Furthermore, I see some flavors which support `?` character as a valid input while other variants do not.

Does cron have an authoritative standards document for cron syntax? (E.g. an RFC or an ISO document).  Or is cron just a loose collection of similar tools each with their own syntax rules?